# How to build a node from a hash using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, recursion, hash, nokogiri

Many people usually want to do the opposite transformation, but I want to build a node from a Ruby hash (with many nested hashes and even arrays):

```
my_hash = {
  "name" => "Something",
  "property_1" => "Something"
  "nested_array_items" => [{ "name" => "Nasty nested array item", 
                  "advice" => "Use recursive function" },
                 { "name" => "yes this is an array",
                  "notice" => "not necessarily the same keys"}],
  "nested_many_levels" => { "additional_items" => { "ok_stop_here" => true } },
}
```

I have a Nokogiri node that should contain all this. How do I define the function to do it?

Each sub-node should be named with the name of the key, replacing eventually "`_`" by "`-`". For arrays, use the singular of the name of the key for each item, assuming it is a regular plural (ending with an "s", raising an error otherwise).

For example the hash given above should become:

```xml
...
<name>something></name>
<property_1>Something</property_1>
<nested_array_items>
  <nested_array_item>
    <name>Nasty nested array item</name>
    <advice>Use recursive function</advice>
  </nested_array_item>
  <nested_array_item>
    <name>yes this is an array</name>
    <notice>not necessarily the same keys</notice>
  </nested_array_item>
</nested_array_items>
<nested_many_levels>
  <additional_items>
      <ok_stop_here>true</ok_stop_here>
  </additional_items>
</nested_many_levels>
...
```

Comment: Or maybe Nokogiri already provides a helper that does this ?

Comment: I attempted to answer this question, but I've down voted it because your requirements are not clear. You provide some sample input, but no sample output to go with it. You then provide sample output based on incomplete input. What should happen with `nested_many_levels`? If you edit the question to fix these issues, I will happily switch my vote.

Comment: You're right, this wasn't clear. I have rewritten the output sample so it matches the input hash sample. Hope it's better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I realised building nodes from a hash wasn't my best option (in my case, I'd want to have the full XML structure, even if some nodes are empty because of missing hash content).

Therefore I'm using an XML template node that already contains the full structure I want, with only arrays of length 1. So rather that building new nodes, I'm duplicating the existing one as many times as I need (preprocessing), and then I replace the content.

Because this is only painful for arrays, let's assume my `contents` variable, is, for the very first call, only a hash that contains arrays (but then these arrays' items can be values, hashes,...)

**Duplicating template nodes of custom_xml**

```
contents.map do |content, items|
    tmp = custom_xml.search("#{content.to_s}")      # Should be unique !
    if tmp.count > 1 then raise "ERROR : multiple nodes match XPATH //#{content.to_s}" end
    if tmp.count == 0 then raise "ERROR : No node matches \"search #{content.to_s}\" DEBUG : #{custom_xml.serialize}" end
    array_node = tmp.first # <array><item>...</item></array>
    template_node = array_node.first_element_child  
    # Okay, we have the customXML node corresponding to the first item of the content
    # We need to duplicate it as many times as needed
    items.each_with_index do |item, item_index|
        next if item_index == 0 # Skip the first one.
        array_node << template_node.dup
    end
end
```

Then after this preprocessing is done, it's possible to actually substitute variables of the array_node(s) by calling `replace_node_vars_recursively(array_node, items)`

Note that for the very frst call, we indeed have an `array_node` with `items`, but the recursive function needs to handle hashes and values as well. So let's use the word `content` to designate this stuff, and `node`

**Recursively change the nodes text with a "content"**

```
def  replace_node_vars_recursively(node, content)
    if content.nil?
        puts "WARNING : nil content trying to be assigned to node #{node.name}"
    elsif content.is_a?(Hash)
        # Every key in content SHOULD have a matching child node !
        content.each do |key, val|
            candidates = node.search("#{key.to_s}")     # Should be unique !
            if candidates.count > 1 
                puts "WARNING : multiple child_nodes match -->#{key.to_s}<--, skipping"
                next
            elsif candidates.count == 0 
                puts "WARNING : No child node matches \"#{key.to_s}\" "
                next
            end
            replace_node_vars_recursively(candidates.first, val)
        end
    # Array recursion (rq : array contains either a Hash or a value.)
    elsif content.is_a?(Array)
        # Let's rename the variables !
        array_items = content 
        array_node = node
        if array_items.count != array_node.element_children.count # /!\ using just "children" will return empty nodes !!!
            raise "ERROR : array length (#{array_items.count}) != number of nodes of #{array_node.name} (#{array_node.element_children.count}) !"
        end
        array_node.element_children.each_with_index do |child_node, index|  # Assume item is another content_hash. Wouldn't make sense (for me) to have just a value there...
            replace_node_vars_recursively(child_node, content[index])
        end
    # Value terminaison
    elsif content.is_a?(String) or content.is_a?(Integer) or content.is_a?(Float) or content.is_a?(Symbol) or content.is_a?(Date) or content.is_a?(Datetime)
        node.content = content.to_s
        puts "Replacing variable #{node.name} by #{content.to_s}"
    else 
        puts content
        raise "ERROR: unknown variable type for variable replacement !"
    end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Okay, here's my code that seems to work !

```
def  build_node_recursively(node, content_hash, xml_document)
    content_hash.each do |key, val|
        new_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "#{key.to_s}", xml_document
        # Val can be : a value | an array of hashes | another hash
        if val.is_a?(Array)
            item_label = key.to_s.singularize
            val.each do |item|  # Assume item is another content_hash. Wouldn't make sense (for me) to have just a value...
                item_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new item_label, xml_document
                new_node << build_node_recursively(item_node, item)
            end
        elsif val.is_a?(Hash)
            build_node_recursively(new_node, val)
        else
            new_node.content = val.to_s
        end
        node << new_node
    end
end
```

Comment: I have down voted your answer because the code does not actually run. Separate from needing `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'` you fail to pass `xml_document` as the third param recursively to your method, yet even with that change the code fails to run using your own sample input.

Comment: Aaah you're right on many points. First I ran this code from a Rails application, so the inflector wwas already loaded. The it seems I haven't posted the latest version of my code... that unfortunately I haven't kept because I realized I didn't need to build a node, but rather only replace the content of already existing nodes...